# select input late update using watch in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, html-select

I have three select-option structures, all of them works ok independently. Vue 2.6

I want to link them using conditions (v-if)

but

I am watching how variables change and changing variables values (true false).

When in select2 if I choose Empty I want select 3 to be gone but I have a delay on this in the way I am doing it

But there is a delay when I select a value from select 2 using newValue == '3'.

How can I fix this.
Is there any ohter way, that is the way this must be done, maybe i am trying to dicover warm water?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Select 1</h3>
        <select v-model="selected1">
            <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
            <option v-for="exception in exceptions" :key="exception.value" :value="exception.value">
                {{ exception.text }}
            </option>
        </select>
        <div>Selected: {{ selected1 }}</div>

        <div v-if="operationSelected">
        <h3>Select 2</h3>
            <select v-model="selected2">
                <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
                <option v-for="operation in operations" :key="operation.value" :value="operation.value">
                    {{ operation.text }}
                </option>
            </select>
            <div>Selected: {{ selected2 }}</div>
        </div>

        <div v-if="operationSelected ">
            <div v-if="!isEmpty">
        <h3>Select 3</h3>
                <select v-model="selected3">
                    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
                    <option v-for="description in descriptions" :key="description.value" :value="description.value">
                        {{ description.text }}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <div>Selected: {{ selected3 }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'select-option-render-conditional',
    data() {
        return {
            exceptions: [
                { text: 'Exception1', value: '1' },
                { text: 'Exception2', value: '2' },
                { text: 'Exception3', value: '3' }
            ],
            operations: [
                { text: 'In', value: '1' },
                { text: 'Not in', value: '2' },
                { text: 'Empty', value: '3' }
            ],
            descriptions: [
                { text: 'description1', value: '1' },
                { text: 'description2', value: '2' },
                { text: 'description3', value: '3' }
            ],
            operationSelected: false,
            selected1: '',
            selected2: '1',
            selected3: '',
            isEmpty:false
        }
    },
    watch: {
        selected1() {
            this.operationSelected=true
        },
        selected2(oldValue, newValue) {
            if (newValue == '3') {
                console.log('3 selected')
                this.isEmpty = true
            }
            if (newValue != '3') {
                console.log('3 not selected')
                this.isEmpty = false
            }
        }
    }
    

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a computed property instead a watcher for this purpose

like this

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Select 1</h3>
        <select v-model="selected1">
            <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
            <option v-for="exception in exceptions" :key="exception.value" :value="exception.value">
                {{ exception.text }}
            </option>
        </select>
        <div>Selected: {{ selected1 }}</div>

        <div v-if="operationSelected">
            <h3>Select 2</h3>
            <select v-model="selected2">
                <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
                <option v-for="operation in operations" :key="operation.value" :value="operation.value">
                    {{ operation.text }}
                </option>
            </select>
            <div>Selected: {{ selected2 }}</div>
        </div>

        <div v-if="operationSelected ">
            <div v-if="!setIsEmptyValue">
                <h3>Select 3</h3>
                <select v-model="selected3">
                    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
                    <option v-for="description in descriptions" :key="description.value" :value="description.value">
                        {{ description.text }}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <div>Selected: {{ selected3 }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'select-option-render-conditional',
    data() {
        return {
            exceptions: [
                { text: 'Exception1', value: '1' },
                { text: 'Exception2', value: '2' },
                { text: 'Exception3', value: '3' }
            ],
            operations: [
                { text: 'In', value: '1' },
                { text: 'Not in', value: '2' },
                { text: 'Empty', value: '3' }
            ],
            descriptions: [
                { text: 'description1', value: '1' },
                { text: 'description2', value: '2' },
                { text: 'description3', value: '3' }
            ],
            operationSelected: false,
            selected1: '',
            selected2: '1',
            selected3: '',
            isEmpty:false
        }
    },   
    watch: {
        selected1() {
            this.operationSelected=true
        },        
    },
    computed: {
        setIsEmptyValue() {
            if (this.selected2 == '3') {
                // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties
                this.isEmpty = true
            }
            if (this.selected2 != '3') {
                // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties
                this.isEmpty = false
            }
                return this.isEmpty 
        }
    }
    

}
```

still I think would be great to know how to use it with watcher only